# Obter dados de uma Api JSON para uma Data View Grid

Tags: json, vb.net

Estou a utilizar uma Api (Json): [API](https://nunofcguerreiro.com/api-euromillions-json?result=2017-11)

E gostaria que ao abrir o programa obtive-se automaticamente os dados da api, na DataViewGrid, como poderei resolver?

PS: Já utilizei newsoftjson

Comment: Boa tarde, você quer dizer "Newtonsoft"?